# Storing array in multiple mysql columns

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms

Iam struggling with storing my data from dynamic form - rows can be added/removed during it is filled.

Output from this form is array:

```
Array ( [service] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) [desc] => Array ( [0] => Complete service - description [1] => Half Service - description [2] => Break Service - description ) [price] => Array ( [0] => 1000 [1] => 500 [2] => 800 ) [income_sum] => 2300 [odeslat] => Odeslat )
```

Table definition:

```
Column Type Comment
id  int(11) Auto Increment   
order_id    int(11) NULL     
servis_id   tinyint(4) NULL  
price   int(11) NULL     
desc    text NULL
```

FORM definition:

```
<form action="test.php" method="get" id="form">
<div class='container'>
<select name='service[]'>
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">Complete Service</option>
<option value="2">Half Service</option>
<option value="3">Break Service</option>
</select>
Description
<input type='text' name='desc[]'>
Price
<input class='income_count' type='text' name='price[]'>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I dont have any idea how to store these multiple columns with multiple values.
I would use FOREACH, but failed to use it with multiple variables.

Thank you very much,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your test.php get a count to check how many form dataset you have got and loop through it:

```
$total = count($_REQUEST['price']); // get total
$arrService = $_REQUEST['service'];// get  services array
$arrDesc = $_REQUEST['desc']; //get desc array
$arrPrice = $_REQUEST['price']; // get price array 

for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++){  
  $service = $arrService[$i];
  $dsc = $arrDesc[$i];
  $price = $arrPrice[$i];
  //insert those data into database

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you say, yu must use a `for`:

```
 for($i=0;$i<count($values['service']);$i++)
 {
    $service = $values['service'][$i];
    $desc = $values['desc'][$i];
    $price = $values['price'][$i];

    //Now, perform the insert
 }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, thank you too. I struggled with the count of requests too. So Awlad's help helped me more. Thanks anyway, Oscar.